# Call typescript function from cshmlt using knockout

Tags: razor, knockout.js, typescript

Trying to call remove(object:any) function of typescript from cshtml using knockout, but not able to:

```
    module DatawareHouseApp {
        declare var rowList: string[];
        declare var colList: string[];
        declare var measuresList: string[];
        export var rowTag: Tag[];
        export var colTag: Tag[];

        export class MainPage
        {

            public RemoveFromRows(object: any)
            {
                alert("In");
                console.log(object);
            }
        }
}
```

**CSHTML:**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach :rowCols">
    <li>
          <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
                 <a class="tagit-close" data-bind="click: RemoveFromRows">x</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code:

```
data-bind="click: RemoveFromRows"
```

You definitely want to change `public RemoveFromRows(object: any) {` to `public RemoveFromRows = (object: any) => {`. Here are some [more docs about arrow functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess. You're within the context of the foreach loop, and trying to reference the global namespace. Maybe $root.RemoveFromRows?

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

I'll be back later to expand/troubleshoot if no one else has helped.